# How to set sessions in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

I am trying to use sessions in Laravel PHP

I used this

`Session::set('store_id', $store->store_id);`
`Session::set('user_id', $store->id);`

and used them like

`Session::get('store_id')`

I used class like 
`use Session;`

But I am getting error

`FatalErrorException in Manager.php line 137: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()`

What is it saying and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`put()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data) or [`push()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data) methods. Or just use the [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#using-the-session) helper. Set the data:

```
session(['store_id' => $store->store_id]);
```

Get the data:

```
session('store_id');
```

Comment: Teach me `put()` and `push()` methods to set and get session data

Comment: @Alex if you want to learn how these methods work, click one of the links in my answer and read the related docs.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that! It's great! Thank you :) Can you tell me is there is a performance difference or security difference between these two methods?

Comment: One last thing! Can I used `session_regenerate_id()` on top of every custom controllers? or there is a different method to it?